# Amazon ECS Task fails with STOPPED (CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daem)

Tags: permissions, amazon-vpc, amazon-ecr, aws-fargate

I have set up an `AWS VPC` and am trying to deploy a functional container in `ECS` on a `Fargate launch type` but the task always fails with:

```
STOPPED (CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daem)
```

Task role context:

```
ecsTaskExecutionRole
```

Which has the following IAM permissions:

[image]

The repo permissions are such:

```
{
  "Version": "2008-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "AllowPull",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::aws_account_id:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole"
      },
      "Action": [
        "ecr:BatchCheckLayerAvailability",
        "ecr:BatchGetImage",
        "ecr:DescribeImages",
        "ecr:DescribeRepositories",
        "ecr:GetAuthorizationToken",
        "ecr:GetDownloadUrlForLayer",
        "ecr:GetRepositoryPolicy",
        "ecr:ListImages"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

For security, the actual id is replaced with `aws_account_id`

**I have followed [this guide](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-pull-container-api-error-ecr/) on troubleshooting which states:**

You can receive this error due to one of the following issues:

- Your launch type doesn't have access to the Amazon ECR endpoint

  I believe [Fargate has access to ECR](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ecs-pull-container-api-error-ecr/)
- Your Amazon ECR repository policy restricts access to repository images

  I believe it permits `pull access` for role used - see repo permissions above.
- Your AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM) role doesn't have the right permissions to pull or push images

  I believe it does have necessary permissions  - See task role context above.
- The image can't be found

  The image is in ECR and permissions are above
- Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) access is denied by your Amazon Virtual Private Cloud (Amazon VPC) gateway endpoint policy

  I believe so.  IAM permission is set per above `S3 read access`, furthermore, no explicit endpoint policy has been put in place, which [according to docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints-access.html), means full access by default.

To pull images, Amazon ECS must communicate with the Amazon ECR endpoint.

Routing table defined in the VPC:

[image]

with all of the VPC's subnets associated.  So the VPC and anything running in it should be able to see the internet - The security policy used for the task currently allows all ports (temp while troubleshooting ECR issue).

> What am I missing that I am still getting this error?

**This works using an EC2 instance** - If I create a task that uses an EC2 instance with all other things being equal (where applicable) EXCEPT

```
EC2:  Network Mode = Bridge 
Fargate: Network Mode = awsvpc
```

The container provisions and runs - and the web app that runs in container is running normally.  But in Fargate, Network Mode MUST be awsvpc

```
Fargate only supports network mode ‘awsvpc’.
```

> I think this is where the problem resides, but do not know how to
>   remedy.

**The task definition is:**

```
{
  "ipcMode": null,
  "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws_account_id:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "containerDefinitions": [
    {
      "dnsSearchDomains": null,
      "logConfiguration": {
        "logDriver": "awslogs",
        "secretOptions": null,
        "options": {
          "awslogs-group": "/ecs/deploy-test-web",
          "awslogs-region": "us-west-2",
          "awslogs-stream-prefix": "ecs"
        }
      },
      "entryPoint": [],
      "portMappings": [
        {
          "hostPort": 8080,
          "protocol": "tcp",
          "containerPort": 8080
        }
      ],
      "command": null,
      "linuxParameters": null,
      "cpu": 1,
      "environment": [],
      "resourceRequirements": null,
      "ulimits": null,
      "dnsServers": null,
      "mountPoints": [],
      "workingDirectory": null,
      "secrets": null,
      "dockerSecurityOptions": null,
      "memory": null,
      "memoryReservation": null,
      "volumesFrom": [],
      "stopTimeout": null,
      "image": "csrepo/test-web-v4.0.6",
      "startTimeout": null,
      "dependsOn": null,
      "disableNetworking": null,
      "interactive": null,
      "healthCheck": null,
      "essential": true,
      "links": null,
      "hostname": null,
      "extraHosts": null,
      "pseudoTerminal": null,
      "user": null,
      "readonlyRootFilesystem": null,
      "dockerLabels": null,
      "systemControls": null,
      "privileged": null,
      "name": "test-web-six"
    }
  ],
  "placementConstraints": [],
  "memory": "2048",
  "taskRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::aws_account_id:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
  "compatibilities": [
    "EC2",
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "taskDefinitionArn": "arn:aws:ecs:us-west-2:aws_account_id:task-definition/deploy-test-web3:4",
  "family": "deploy-test-web3",
  "requiresAttributes": [
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.logging-driver.awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.execution-role-awslogs"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.19"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.private-registry-authentication.secretsmanager"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.task-iam-role"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "com.amazonaws.ecs.capability.docker-remote-api.1.18"
    },
    {
      "targetId": null,
      "targetType": null,
      "value": null,
      "name": "ecs.capability.task-eni"
    }
  ],
  "pidMode": null,
  "requiresCompatibilities": [
    "FARGATE"
  ],
  "networkMode": "awsvpc",
  "cpu": "1024",
  "revision": 4,
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "inferenceAccelerators": null,
  "proxyConfiguration": null,
  "volumes": []
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by removing and creating again ECR repository

Comment: Recreating the repo with a different name solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this AWS managed policy: AmazonEC2ContainerServiceforEC2Role

Comment: Did not fix.  Still get `STOPPED (CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daem)`

Comment: @RoyHinkley In your policy, do you have this attribute: "Resource": "*"?

Comment: All policies in the role you suggested have `All resources` defined `"*"`